What early studies are the source of commonly-given 6-week bone healing time?
The expected healing time for a fracture is approximately 6 weeks for an upper limb fracture (twice that for a lower limb fracture, roughly half that for Children’s fractures).
Influential orthopedic textbooks, such as Campbell's Operative Orthopaedics and Rockwood and Green's Fractures in Adults and Children give these timings, but do not cite a source. It just seems to be taken as a fact.
In clinical practice, I have found these timings to be fairly accurate. But where did these timings originally come from?
The earliest paper I can find on bone healing is a paper by Clay Murray from 1941(1), but even that is more focused on physiology and treatment.
Pioneering works by surgeons like Sir Reginald Watson-Jones and Dr. Robert Danis contributed to understanding fracture healing but did not define these
specific durations.
Studies on the biology and mechanics of bone healing, such as
those by Dr. Stephan Perren on the "strain theory" of fracture healing, have informed guidelines but didn't specify the commonly cited time frames.
What was the original source of the "six weeks" timeframe? What is the earliest published research that would have led to this now everyday knowledge?
(1) THE TIMING OF THE FRACTURE-HEALING PROCESS
Its Influence on the Choice and Application of Treatment Methods
MURRAY, CLAY RAY The Journal of Bone & Joint Surgery 23(3):p 598-606, July 1941.

Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

What links would you suggest to show that I found nothing?

If you found nothing then what search terms did you use? Did you try Google Scholar?

I will reword my question to emphasise the key point. I want to know where the timings came from: what is the earliest published research that would have led to this now everyday knowledge.

I think it's quite possible that there is no original research source for this kind of information, which can also come from personal experience and then spread informally through professional circles and medical education as "folklore".

Yes, that is quite possible, but it's a question that I get asked all the time, and I don't know the answer. I think there's a good chance that someone out there can given an informed opinion, though.

Indeed it's an interesting question, just may not be an answerable one!

Much better question following your edits. Thank you!
